# Problem with defining own sectioning with color gradient

Tags: sectioning, color, gradient

I want to define a special sectioning type for my CV. But I have problem which I can't figure out myself. I got the following code which produces the section heading with a color gradient how I would like it to be. Using it for the first section is working fine, but for the following sections I get always the same result which was written in the first section. The following code will illustrate the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,positioning,fit}
\tikzset{
  zero sep/.style = {inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
}
\begin{document}
  \newsavebox{\tempbox}
  \newcommand\tikzsection[1]{%
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikzsection]
      \node [minimum width=50mm, minimum height=2.5mm, fill=white, zero sep] (box node) {};
      \node (text node) [text=white, right=10pt of box node.east, anchor=west,  zero sep] {\normalfont \Large \bfseries #1};
      \node [fit=(box node.north west) (text node.south east) (text node.north west) (box node.south east)] {};
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
    \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [text width=50mm, minimum height=2.5mm, fill=white, zero sep] (boxnode) {};
        \node [text=white, right=10pt of boxnode.east, anchor=west,  zero sep] (textnode) {\normalfont \Large \bfseries #1};
        \node (fitnode) [fit=(boxnode.north west) (textnode.south east) (textnode.north west) (boxnode.south east)] {};
        \shade[path fading=tikzsection, fit fading=false,left color=blue, right color=black]
        (fitnode.north west) rectangle (fitnode.south east);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{lrbox}
    % Now we use the fading in another picture:
    \section{\usebox\tempbox{}}%
  }

  \tikzsection{First section}
  Some text
  \tikzsection{Secoooooond section}
  Some text
\tikzsection{Short}
  Some text


\end{document}
```

Can someone figure out for me what is going wrong here? Why is the section titled as "Secoooooond section" rendered as "First section"?

[image: 3 sections]

`\listfiles`gives me the following list:

- article.cls 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
- size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
- tikz.sty 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
- pgf.sty 2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
- pgfrcs.sty 2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
- everyshi.sty 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
- pgfrcs.code.tex pgfcore.sty 2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
- graphicx.sty 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
- keyval.sty 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
- graphics.sty 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
- trig.sty 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
- graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
- xetex.def 2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)
- pgfsys.sty 2013/11/30 v3.0.0(rcs-revision 1.47)
- pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09 (rcs-revision 1.9)
- pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16 (rcs-revision 1.4)
- xcolor.sty 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions
- color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
- pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty 2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
- pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty 2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
- pgffor.sty 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)

Comment: Is this different from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215895/color-gradient-in-tikzpicture-from-top-to-bottom-corner and/or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215856/section-heading-in-moderncv-with-color-gradient?

Comment: @cfr yes it is a different question. This is regarding another problem as described above

Comment: @AdrianPfeifle The code provided does not produce the image provided...

Comment: As @PaulGaborit says, the code you posted does not have the issue you show. I get the correct section titles for all 3 sections.

Comment: @cfr also when you compile more than once? When I compiled the first time it was looking correctly but compiling the 2nd time I got the picture above

Comment: @AdrianPfeifle Yep. I compiled 4 times just to be sure.

Comment: @cfr that's very weird, because I get the result as in the screenshot above

Comment: With exactly that code and nothing else? Clear out any generated files, create a document containing just that code, and then compile it twice or more. I've now tested multiple compilations on two different computers and cannot reproduce the problem you are reporting.

Comment: @cfr still weird. Tried it a few more times. Deleted everything, changed folders, but I always get the result as posted above

Comment: @AdrianPfeifle On my PC (pdfTeX Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 - TeX Live 2014) I get the "correct" result, if we want to consider "correct" an uneven length of the bars (due to section names center aligned). By the way, give a look at `moderncv` class.

Comment: @AdrianPfeifle: I suspect that one of your pacakges must be out of date. I'd suggest you add `\listfiles` just _before_ `\begin{document}` and add the package versions to your question so we can determine the package that is responsible.  Alternatively, update to TeXLive2014.

Comment: @Astrinus ok I don't know about the uneven length of the bars yet. That's not what I want. I want the bars to be aligned on the left side with even length

Comment: @PeterGrill I updated my post with the list of packages and their versions

Comment: You have `graphicx` outdated. All other version are the same, except for `xetex` (I used pdfLaTeX). With XeLaTeX all the sections output "First section", so the problem is XeLaTeX.

Comment: @Astrinus Ha! That's the problem, thanks!. I use XeLaTeX because pdfLaTeX is not working with my moderncv. Did you use the same version of `xetex` as I did or is it also not working with the newest version?

Comment: Version 2014/07/25 v4.03, the last one. Why pdfLaTeX is not working? My CV is made with `moderncv` and pdfLaTeX and I had no problem. Maybe an update it's enough.

Comment: @Astrinus so with XeLaTeX it's not working at all? So what can I do if I want to integrate this in my moderncv where I have to use XeLaTeX?

Comment: First try to update pdfLaTeX, then retry compiling with it. I never used XeLaTeX before, so I don't know which are its pitfalls. In future, state also the program you are using for compiling: a lot of time hadn't be spent on figuring out why on your system won't work and on our it does. By the way, *WHY* precisely you need XeLaTeX? What feature do you need that pdfLaTeX doesn't have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *workaround* for XeLaTeX : use a different name for each `tikzfadingfrompicture`!

## Third Version

*(working with XeLaTeX and with the same features as second version.)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,positioning,fit,calc}
\tikzset{
  zero sep/.style = {inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
}

\newcommand\tikzsection[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\randref{rand}
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikzsection \randref]
    \node[fill=white,anchor=south east,zero sep,minimum width=5cm,minimum height=2.5mm] (box node){};
    \node [text=white,anchor=base west,text depth=5pt,text height=12pt,zero sep,
    font=\normalfont\Large\bfseries,right=10pt of box node,
    text width=5.9cm,align=left] (text node) {#1};
    \node [fit={(box node)(text node)
      },zero sep] (myfit) {};
    \path let \p1=(myfit.south west), \p2=(myfit.north east), \n1={\x2-\x1}, \n2={\y2-\y1} in
    \pgfextra{\xdef\lenx{\n1} \xdef\leny{\n2}};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
  \section[#1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=.5*5pt-.5*12pt]
      \path[path fading=tikzsection \randref, fit fading=false,left color=blue, right color=black]
      (-.5*\lenx,-.5*\leny) rectangle ++(\lenx,\leny);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\tikzsection{First section}
Some text
\tikzsection{Secoooooond segtion}
Some text
\tikzsection{Short}
Some text

\end{document}
```

## Second Version

Here is a new version:

- with correct position of the tikz fading,
- without a save box,
- with care about depth and height of title,
- with correct alignment of the baseline,
- with a fixed length (15cm) for the title (and the fading).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,positioning,fit,calc}
\tikzset{
  zero sep/.style = {inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
}

\newcommand\tikzsection[1]{%
  \pgfmathsetmacro\randref{rand}
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikzsection \randref]
    \fill[white] (0,0) rectangle +(5cm,2.5mm);
    \node [text=white,anchor=base west,text depth=5pt,text height=12pt,zero sep,font=\normalfont\Large\bfseries,
    text width=10cm,align=left]
    (text node) at (5cm+10pt,0) {#1};
    \node [fit={(0,0)(text node)},zero sep] (myfit) {};
    \path let \p1=(myfit.south west), \p2=(myfit.north east), \n1={\x2-\x1}, \n2={\y2-\y1} in
    \pgfextra{\xdef\lenx{\n1} \xdef\leny{\n2}};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
  \typeout{lenx:\lenx}
  \typeout{leny:\leny}
  \section[#1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=.5*5pt-.5*12pt]
      \path[path fading=tikzsection \randref, fit fading=false,left color=blue, right color=black]
      (-.5*\lenx,-.5*\leny) rectangle ++(\lenx,\leny);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\tikzsection{First section}
Some text
\tikzsection{Secoooooond segtion}
Some text
\tikzsection{Short}
Some text

\end{document}
```

## First version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,positioning,fit}
\tikzset{
  zero sep/.style = {inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
}
\begin{document}


  \newsavebox{\tempbox}
  \newcommand\tikzsection[1]{%
    \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=tikzsection #1]
      \node [minimum width=50mm, minimum height=2.5mm, fill=white, zero sep] (box node) {};
      \node (text node) [text=white, right=10pt of box node.east, anchor=west,  zero sep] {\normalfont \Large \bfseries #1};
      \node [fit=(box node.north west) (text node.south east) (text node.north west) (box node.south east)] {};
    \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
    \begin{lrbox}{\tempbox}%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [text width=50mm, minimum height=2.5mm, fill=white, zero sep] (boxnode) {};
        \node [text=white, right=10pt of boxnode.east, anchor=west,  zero sep] (textnode) {\normalfont \Large \bfseries #1};
        \node (fitnode) [fit=(boxnode.north west) (textnode.south east) (textnode.north west) (boxnode.south east)] {};
        \shade[path fading=tikzsection #1, fit fading=false,left color=blue, right color=black]
        (fitnode.north west) rectangle (fitnode.south east);
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{lrbox}
    % Now we use the fading in another picture:
    \section[#1]{\usebox\tempbox{}}%
  }

  \tikzsection{First section}
  Some text
  \tikzsection{Secoooooond section}
  Some text
\tikzsection{Short}
  Some text


\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Maybe you can still help me, because now I have two new questions. 1.) I would like to align the bars with a fixed length and the headings of the sections left justified (to the right side of the bars)

Comment: 2.) is it possible to have a "fixed" fading? I mean now no matter how short or long the section heading is the last letter always has black color. But lets say I want the whole color fade to be fixed with starting with the left color at the left side of the bars and ending with the right color after 15 cm. So if a section heading is shorter than 15 cm the last letter has the color that the would occur for the fixed color fade at the position of the last letter

Comment: I tried now to include this in my `moderncv` but obviously I can't just use it like that since the `\section` command is already defined in `moderncv`. I tried to redefine it in `moderncv` and `moderncvstyleclassic` but it still gives me errors. Do you know what I have to do to use what you did in my `moderncv` instead of `\section`?

Comment: oh and I just realized when I was testing your new version I compiled with pdfLaTeX and it was working fine. But when I compile with XeLaTeX I can see only the section heading but not the bars to the left

Comment: BTW im using XeLaTeX because I'm using fonts that are not available in pdfLaTeX

Comment: @AdrianPfeifle Ok. I see the same problem with XeLaTeX. 
I'll try to fix that.